# Java Application Does not Run after Adding Web Service

Tags: java, web-services

I have two Java applications which are running independently on two different servers.

1. Frontend Application - Runs on Glassfish Server
2. Backend Application  - Runs on Apache Tomcat

Initially when I created the backend application (a fresh maven web project) it was deployed to the server and was running. However, I wanted to include the web service functionality and once I did that I've been getting the below error.

```
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/TM_BLogic
OK - Undeployed application at context path [/TM_BLogic]
In-place deployment at G:\School\Advance Programming\Assignment Data\Project\TM_BLogic\target\TM_BLogic-1.0
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Ftrevi%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext3621440620297529295.xml&path=/TM_BLogic
FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/TM_BLogic] but context failed to start
```

I've tried deploying the application by changing the context path, but still getting the same error.

I'm developing the application on Netbeans 12 and using JDK 1.8 on Tomcat Server 8.

Appreciate if anyone could advise as to why the application is not getting deployed on the server environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be due to a limitation on NetBeans 12 or maybe it does not support. I resolved this issue by reinstalling NetBeans 11.3 along with jdk 1.8.